# SharePoint import error - 'Access Denied'

Tags: sharepoint, import, access-denied

I am trying to import a site collection and I get the following error:

```
[9/22/2009 4:59:43 PM]: Start Time: 9/22/2009 4:59:43 PM.
[9/22/2009 4:59:43 PM]: Progress: Initializing Import.
[9/22/2009 5:00:11 PM]: Progress: Starting content import.
[9/22/2009 5:00:11 PM]: Progress: De-Serializing Objects to Database.
[9/22/2009 5:00:11 PM]: Debug: Security check failed in OnWebImport
[9/22/2009 5:00:11 PM]: Progress: Importing Folder /.
[9/22/2009 5:00:11 PM]: FatalError: Access denied.
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.HandleUnauthorizedAccessException(UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetFileAndFolderProperties(String bstrUrl, String bstrStartUrl, ListDocsFlags ListDocsFlags, Boolean bThrowException, Int32& phrStatus, Object& pvarFiles, Object& pvarDirs, UInt32& pdwNumberOfFiles, UInt32& pdwNumberOfDirs)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.GetFileOrFolderProperties(String strUrl, ListDocsFlags listDocsFlags, Boolean throwException)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFolder.PropertiesCore(Boolean throwException)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFolder.get_Properties()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFolder.get_UniqueId()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.FolderSerializer.AddFolderToImportMaps(Guid folderId, SPFolder folder, ImportObjectManager objectManager)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.FolderSerializer.GetFolder(SerializationInfoHelper infoHelper, SPWeb parentWeb, ImportObjectManager objectManager)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.FolderSerializer.SetObjectData(Object obj, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context, ISurrogateSelector selector)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.XmlFormatter.ParseObject(Type objectType, Boolean isChildObject)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.XmlFormatter.DeserializeObject(Type objectType, Boolean isChildObject, DeploymentObject envelope)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.XmlFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.ObjectSerializer.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.ImportObjectManager.ProcessObject(XmlReader xmlReader)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.SPImport.DeserializeObjects()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.SPImport.Run()
[9/22/2009 5:00:12 PM]: Progress: Import Completed.
[9/22/2009 5:00:12 PM]: Finish Time: 9/22/2009 5:00:12 PM.
[9/22/2009 5:00:12 PM]: Completed with 0 warnings.
[9/22/2009 5:00:12 PM]: Completed with 1 errors.
```

The command I am executing is:

```
Stsadm -o import -url http://spssvr:2000/ -filename sps_export.dat
```

**Environment:**
**OS:** Windows Server 2008
**SharePoint:** MOSS 2007 
**SharePoint Version:** 12.0.0.6421
**User Account:** Administrator
**Permissions:** Administrators, Site Owners

The export was done by an admin from a different environment. The log shows that the export was completed successfully.
I saw somewhere that turning off UAC would help, but that did not solve my problem. Any ideas what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you having issues with the [local loopback check](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896861)?

Comment: Not sure if this is the problem, I'll test and report back.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I'll answer my own question. Not sure exactly where the problem is but using **localhost** instead of server name 'spssvr' worked! Must be something to do with how the environment is configured.