# SharePoint import error - 'Access Denied'

Tags: sharepoint, import, export

I'm trying to import data from another environment to a new server that we just setup. I was initially running into [this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1462678/sharepoint-import-error-access-denied), but I eventually resolved it by using **localhost** instead of the server name. Now, the import completes but skips some items with the following error:

```
[9/28/2009 6:34:30 PM]: Progress: Importing File _catalogs/masterpage/Forms/AllItems.aspx.
[9/28/2009 6:34:30 PM]: Error: Current item failed in the export with the error message: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).
[9/28/2009 6:34:30 PM]: Progress: Importing File _catalogs/masterpage/Forms/DispForm.aspx.
[9/28/2009 6:34:30 PM]: Error: Current item failed in the export with the error message: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).
[9/28/2009 6:34:30 PM]: Progress: Importing File _catalogs/masterpage/Forms/EditForm.aspx.
[9/28/2009 6:34:30 PM]: Error: Current item failed in the export with the error message: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).
[9/28/2009 6:34:30 PM]: Progress: Importing File _catalogs/masterpage/Forms/mod-view.aspx.
[9/28/2009 6:34:30 PM]: Error: Current item failed in the export with the error message: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).
[9/28/2009 6:34:30 PM]: Progress: Importing File _catalogs/masterpage/Forms/my-sub.aspx.
[9/28/2009 6:34:30 PM]: Error: Current item failed in the export with the error message: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).
[9/28/2009 6:34:30 PM]: Progress: Importing File _catalogs/masterpage/Forms/Publishing Master Page/PublishingMasterTemplate.master.
[9/28/2009 6:34:30 PM]: Error: Current item failed in the export with the error message: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).
[9/28/2009 6:34:30 PM]: Progress: Importing File _catalogs/masterpage/Forms/Upload.aspx.
[9/28/2009 6:34:30 PM]: Error: Current item failed in the export with the error message: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).
[9/28/2009 6:34:30 PM]: Progress: Importing File _catalogs/masterpage/Forms/View with Title.aspx.
[9/28/2009 6:34:30 PM]: Error: Current item failed in the export with the error message: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).
```

Any idea what could be going on?

**EDIT**

After a bit more digging, I found the following entries in the export log file:

```
[9/23/2009 2:07:46 PM]: Error: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.HandleUnauthorizedAccessException(UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetFileAsByteArray(String bstrUrl, String bstrWebRelativeUrl, Boolean bHonorLevel, Byte iLevel, OpenBinaryFlags grfob)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.FileSerializer.SaveFile(SerializationInfo info, ExportObjectManager objectManager, ExportDataFileManager fileManager, SPExportSettings settings, SPWeb parentWeb, Boolean isGhosted, String setupPath, String setupPathUser, Byte setupPathVersion, String webRelativeFileUrl, Int32 size, Byte level)
[9/23/2009 2:07:46 PM]: Progress: Exporting File _catalogs/masterpage/Forms/DispForm.aspx.
[9/23/2009 2:07:46 PM]: Error: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.HandleUnauthorizedAccessException(UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetFileAsByteArray(String bstrUrl, String bstrWebRelativeUrl, Boolean bHonorLevel, Byte iLevel, OpenBinaryFlags grfob)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.FileSerializer.SaveFile(SerializationInfo info, ExportObjectManager objectManager, ExportDataFileManager fileManager, SPExportSettings settings, SPWeb parentWeb, Boolean isGhosted, String setupPath, String setupPathUser, Byte setupPathVersion, String webRelativeFileUrl, Int32 size, Byte level)
[9/23/2009 2:07:46 PM]: Progress: Exporting File _catalogs/masterpage/Forms/EditForm.aspx.
[9/23/2009 2:07:46 PM]: Error: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.HandleUnauthorizedAccessException(UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetFileAsByteArray(String bstrUrl, String bstrWebRelativeUrl, Boolean bHonorLevel, Byte iLevel, OpenBinaryFlags grfob)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.FileSerializer.SaveFile(SerializationInfo info, ExportObjectManager objectManager, ExportDataFileManager fileManager, SPExportSettings settings, SPWeb parentWeb, Boolean isGhosted, String setupPath, String setupPathUser, Byte setupPathVersion, String webRelativeFileUrl, Int32 size, Byte level)
[9/23/2009 2:07:46 PM]: Progress: Exporting File _catalogs/masterpage/Forms/mod-view.aspx.
[9/23/2009 2:07:46 PM]: Error: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.HandleUnauthorizedAccessException(UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetFileAsByteArray(String bstrUrl, String bstrWebRelativeUrl, Boolean bHonorLevel, Byte iLevel, OpenBinaryFlags grfob)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.FileSerializer.SaveFile(SerializationInfo info, ExportObjectManager objectManager, ExportDataFileManager fileManager, SPExportSettings settings, SPWeb parentWeb, Boolean isGhosted, String setupPath, String setupPathUser, Byte setupPathVersion, String webRelativeFileUrl, Int32 size, Byte level)
[9/23/2009 2:07:46 PM]: Progress: Exporting File _catalogs/masterpage/Forms/my-sub.aspx.
[9/23/2009 2:07:46 PM]: Error: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.HandleUnauthorizedAccessException(UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetFileAsByteArray(String bstrUrl, String bstrWebRelativeUrl, Boolean bHonorLevel, Byte iLevel, OpenBinaryFlags grfob)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.FileSerializer.SaveFile(SerializationInfo info, ExportObjectManager objectManager, ExportDataFileManager fileManager, SPExportSettings settings, SPWeb parentWeb, Boolean isGhosted, String setupPath, String setupPathUser, Byte setupPathVersion, String webRelativeFileUrl, Int32 size, Byte level)
[9/23/2009 2:07:46 PM]: Progress: Exporting File _catalogs/masterpage/Forms/Publishing Master Page/PublishingMasterTemplate.master.
[9/23/2009 2:07:46 PM]: Error: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.HandleUnauthorizedAccessException(UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetFileAsByteArray(String bstrUrl, String bstrWebRelativeUrl, Boolean bHonorLevel, Byte iLevel, OpenBinaryFlags grfob)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.FileSerializer.SaveFile(SerializationInfo info, ExportObjectManager objectManager, ExportDataFileManager fileManager, SPExportSettings settings, SPWeb parentWeb, Boolean isGhosted, String setupPath, String setupPathUser, Byte setupPathVersion, String webRelativeFileUrl, Int32 size, Byte level)
[9/23/2009 2:07:46 PM]: Progress: Exporting File _catalogs/masterpage/Forms/Upload.aspx.
[9/23/2009 2:07:46 PM]: Error: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.HandleUnauthorizedAccessException(UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetFileAsByteArray(String bstrUrl, String bstrWebRelativeUrl, Boolean bHonorLevel, Byte iLevel, OpenBinaryFlags grfob)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.FileSerializer.SaveFile(SerializationInfo info, ExportObjectManager objectManager, ExportDataFileManager fileManager, SPExportSettings settings, SPWeb parentWeb, Boolean isGhosted, String setupPath, String setupPathUser, Byte setupPathVersion, String webRelativeFileUrl, Int32 size, Byte level)
[9/23/2009 2:07:46 PM]: Progress: Exporting File _catalogs/masterpage/Forms/View with Title.aspx.
[9/23/2009 2:07:46 PM]: Error: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.HandleUnauthorizedAccessException(UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetFileAsByteArray(String bstrUrl, String bstrWebRelativeUrl, Boolean bHonorLevel, Byte iLevel, OpenBinaryFlags grfob)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.FileSerializer.SaveFile(SerializationInfo info, ExportObjectManager objectManager, ExportDataFileManager fileManager, SPExportSettings settings, SPWeb parentWeb, Boolean isGhosted, String setupPath, String setupPathUser, Byte setupPathVersion, String webRelativeFileUrl, Int32 size, Byte level)
```

It seems apparent that the errors occurred during the export process. What might have happened? I'm guessing insufficient privileges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All those files require higher permissions to access than normal, what account are you running the export as? Try logging into the site as that account and see if you are able to access the site http://[yoursite]/_catalogs/masterpage/Forms/AllItems.aspx.

That should tell you straight up if there are permission issue with those files.

Comment: Nope, that seems to not be the problem. That was before I started using **localhost**. This appears to be something else

Comment: I am not the one doing the export and I have not access to the old environment. However, when I asked the admin to browse to that url, they were able to and they sent me a screenshot as well. The files in question, were checked in and approved.

Comment: Thanks Nat,
It turns out they were able to browse the site but did not have full control. This wasn't the solution but your suggestion helped us narrow down to the core of the problem.

Comment: So what was the core of the problem?  And what was the Solution!?!?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried doing just a content db backup on the original DB machine? Then restore and attach that to the db server your new environment is using? THen add that content db to a web app on your new environment...

Comment: I just completed restoring the database and I get "Unknown Error" when attempting to add the content database to the web application.

Comment: Event Log error message:

`Unknown SQL Exception 2812 occured. Additional error information from SQL Server is included below.

Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.proc_GetDatabaseInformation'.`

Comment: Thanks Colin,
I eventually managed to attach the database to a new application. However, a whole lot of domain account/permissions were carried over and I had to manually remove them. (which is why I wanted an export)